# Scrape google search results in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, google-search

I am trying to search google based on keywords and list the Website Title, URL, and Meta Description in a spreadsheet. The code runs through and does a search, but it does not list any entries in my spreadsheet. This used to work fine a few years ago but I'm not sure what has happened now. Any ideas?

```
Sub pDownloadfromGoogle()

Dim tbl                     As Object
Dim lngLoop                 As Long
Dim objhtml                 As Object
Dim strLink                 As String
Dim varData                 As Variant
Dim objIE                   As Object
Dim strTitle                As String
Dim strURL                  As String
Dim strDescription          As String
Dim obj_g_Loop              As Object
Dim obj_tbl                 As Object
Dim objR                    As Object
Dim objR_Loop               As Object
Dim lngLastRow              As Long
Dim strCom1                 As String
Dim strCom2                 As String
Dim strCom3                 As String
Dim lngCtr                  As Long
Dim objNextPage             As Object

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

strCom1 = Sheet2.Range("B1").Value & "+" & Sheet2.Range("C1").Value & "+" & Sheet2.Range("D1").Value
strCom2 = Sheet2.Range("C1").Value & "+" & Sheet2.Range("D1").Value & "+" & Sheet2.Range("B1").Value
strCom3 = Sheet2.Range("D1").Value & "+" & Sheet2.Range("B1").Value & "+" & Sheet2.Range("C1").Value

varData = Array(strCom1, strCom2, strCom3)
    
L = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheet1.Range("C2:F" & L).ClearContents

For lngLoop = 0 To UBound(varData)

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With objIE
        .Visible = False

        .navigate "https://www.google.com/search?q=" & varData(lngLoop)
        Do While .busy 'Or .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop
    End With
        
LoopAgain:
    On Error Resume Next
    Set obj_tbl = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("g")
                
    I = 1
    L = 1
    For Each obj_g_Loop In obj_tbl
        
        L = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            
        Set objR = obj_g_Loop.getElementsByClassName("r")
        strTitle = objR(0).innertext
        strURL = objR(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
            
        Set objR = obj_g_Loop.getElementsByClassName("st")
        strDescription = objR(0).innertext
            
        Sheet1.Cells(L, "C") = strTitle
        Sheet1.Cells(L, "D") = strURL
        Sheet1.Cells(L, "E") = strDescription
                            
        Set objR = Nothing
        strTitle = ""
        strURL = ""
        strDescription = ""
            
    Next obj_g_Loop
    
    lngCtr = lngCtr + 1
    
    If lngCtr < 3 Then
        Set objNextPage = objIE.document.getElementByid("pnnext")
        
        objNextPage.Click
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
        GoTo LoopAgain
    End If
    
'        Stop
         
objIE.Quit

lngCtr = 0
Next lngLoop
            
Sheet1.Range("$C$1:$E$" & L).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
            
MsgBox "Process Complete!"
            
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   
End Sub
```

Comment: "This used to work fine a few years ago but I'm not sure what has happened now" - what do you expect and what is happenning now? your debugging might be helped by removing the `on error ...` temporarily

Comment: Searching Google with the same search terms in different orders produces slightly  different results - I had never thought about this (and secretly just tested the concept ....)! There are soooooooo many questions on StackOverflow about scraping Google results stopping working. They pretty much all resolve around the same html changes. I suggest looking at the newest ones. Also, the code is unnecessarily complex and spaghetti-like. You don't need to keep re-creating the internet explorer object. Create it once, before the loop and work with that instance throughout.

Comment: Please remove `On Error Resume Next` then the error can show and you'll know what's going wrong. I made a test with your code and find that there's no elements which name is `r`. So the error is on this line: `Set objR = obj_g_Loop.getElementsByClassName("r")`.  You can try to debug and edit your code.